# Compare Objects and find matched value

Tags: javascript, lodash

Basically, I want to compare some objects and re-group if the value of specific property is matched.
As following code, If types are same,  I want to regroup as one array of object.

```
var obj = [{id: 94 , type: 'silver'}, {id:95,type:'gold'} , {id:96, type: 'silver'} ]


return newObj = [{id: 94 , type: 'silver'},{id:96, type: 'silver'} ]
```

I would like to use lodash or underscore If It’s possible.
Anyone have great idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want something like this? https://jsbin.com/negeqineje/edit?js,console

```
var metals = [
  {id: 94 , type: 'silver'}, 
  {id: 95, type:'gold'}, 
  {id: 96, type: 'silver'},
  {id: 97, type: 'platinum'},
];

var grouped = metals.reduce(function (grouped, metal) {
  grouped[metal.type] = metals.filter(function (_metal) {
    return (metal.type === _metal.type);
  });

  return grouped;
}, {});
```